# Alternation of sounds in time lapse

Tags: audio, time, unity-game-engine

I tried to write a method that can add any number of sounds to be played in turn at a specified interval.

But the problem is that it works inconsistently. That is:

- a sound played before may repeat several times after a while
- there is no queue of sounds, and so on.

I think problem is that `int i` in the loop is constantly being updated, so there is no priority. But after inscribing check and lowering `int i`, it stopped playing at all.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class OneShot : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioClip[] Sounds;
    public float Timer;
    private float TimerDown;

    void Start ()
    {
        TimerDown = Timer;
        audio.clip = Sounds[0];
        audio.Play();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 1;i < Sounds.Length;i++) 
        {
        if(TimerDown > 0) TimerDown -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(TimerDown < 0) TimerDown = 0;
        if(TimerDown == 0)
            {
            TimerDown = Timer;
            audio.clip = Sounds[i];
            audio.Play();
            }
        else
            {
                i=i-1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a `for` loop here. With your code, you are decreasing your `TimerDown` for every AudioClip in your array. You should only do `TimerDown -= Time.deltaTime` once per Update.

Instead you could store the `i` (index) outside of the update loop.

```
private int i = 0;

void Update ()
{
    if(TimerDown > 0) TimerDown -= Time.deltaTime;
    if(TimerDown < 0) TimerDown = 0;
    if(TimerDown == 0)
    {
        TimerDown = Timer;
        audio.clip = Sounds[i % Sounds.Length];
        i++;
        audio.Play();
    }
}
```